Is there way for an Ignite service to know on its start-up that the data rebalance is in progress?
Can't find it in the Ignite API, but maybe I did't look at the right place yet.
Using Ignite 2.16.0, with its Java API.
There are of course EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STARTED / EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STOPPED events, but the service might miss the EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STARTED event if it kicked off by Ignite after the node started to rebalance a cache. So can the service know that there is data rebalance already happening on its start-up? Like, something like "isTopologyUpdating" property somewhere, or "isCacheRebalancing" maybe?
I want the above for the following use-case: my service hammers Ignite with millions of records from an upstream system, some may already exist in Ignite cache and some not, so I would like to make sure that the two heavy processes (data rebalance and data upserting) are separated in time. Such separation will make at least the logs clearer, and probably might save me from race conditions in the continuous queries consumers.
